# How to dual boot ubuntu from an external hdd, with the ability to boot to windows without the exernal plugged in

Tags: boot, dual-boot, external-hdd

I want to install the new version of Ubuntu on an external hard drive. My only problem is that if I try to turn my computer on without the hard drive plugged in, it wont boot at all. (I am assuming this is because the boot manager is on the external). How can I have Ubuntu on an external but be able to boot to Windows when my external isn't plugged in?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it seems that your boot records and managers are only on the external drive. Normally they are on the internal drive.

You should create a [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and boot into it. It is a handy disk to have anyway.

While in the BRD system, first use gparted to make sure that your internal drive has an active partition with a boot flag set to it. Then running the Recommended repair option should fix the booting problems on your internal hard drive. Reboot.

You should also read this forum post about [How to create an external USB bootable Linux hard drive (without dual-boot)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176132)

Answer (score 1):

One way I know how is to install Grub to just the linux / partition and then add an entry to the Windows bootloader that would start the Grub bootloader and thus boot Ubuntu.

When you install Ubuntu, at the last step there is an advanced option where you get to choose where to install Grub. Just tell it to install to the linux / partition, not the Hdd as a whole.

Now You need to add an entry in the Windows boot manager for Grub.

You will need to download EasyBCD, free for personal non-commercial use:

http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

Grab a downloaded copy of EasyBCD and install it to get started.

Now run EasyBCD

Go to the Add Entry --- Select Linux --- Select GRUB2, and press the Add Entry button.

Go to the BCD Deployment --- Select Install the Windows Vista/7 Bootloader to the MBR,  press Write MBR.

Reboot your PC, and this time you’ll see the Microsoft Boot Manager screen giving you two options: Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Source: https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: Regarding installation of Grub in Ubuntu you say: `Just tell it to install to the linux / partition, not the Hdd as a whole.` Why is this? I have Win 10 on one disk `/dev/sda` and Ubuntu on another disk `/dev/sdb` with Grub 2 at `/dev/sdb` whereas the Linux /root partition is `/dev/sdb5`. Will your solution not work in my case?